# Error on my JavaScript codes

Tags: javascript

I've recently asked this question and I am almost there on my codes. I am creating a function that returns returns a string representing the letter grade corresponding to the given score.

```
Notes:
* (100 - 90) --> 'A'
* (89  - 80) --> 'B'
* (79  - 70) --> 'C'
* (69  - 60) --> 'D'
* (59  -  0) --> 'F'
```

- If the given score is greater than 100 or less than 0, it should return 'INVALID SCORE'.
- If the score is between the 0 and 2 (inclusive) of a given range, return the letter with a '-'
- If the score is between the 8 and 9 (inclusive) of a given range, return the letter with a '+'
- There are is no F+ and there is no F-.

Right now I have this:

```
function convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(score) {
  var fscore;

  switch(true) {
    case (score <= 100 && score >= 90):
       fscore = 'A';
        break;
    case (score <= 89 && score >= 80):
        fscore = 'B';
         break;
    case (score <= 79 && score >= 70):
        fscore = 'C';
         break;
       case (score <= 69 && score >= 60):
        fscore = 'D';
         break;
    case (score <= 59 && score >= 0):
        fscore = 'F';
        break;

    case (score > 100 && score < 0):
        fscore = 'INVALID SCORE';
        break; 

    default:
      return 'INVALID SCORE';
  }

  var last_digit = score%10;
  if(last_digit <=2 && last_digit >= 0 && score != 100){
    fscore+='-';
  }
  else{
    fscore+='+';
  }

  return fscore;
}

var output = convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(91);
console.log(output); // --> 'A-'
```

This code is almost there, except that it shows me the ff issues:

- should return 'A' for scores between 93 and 97

  - should return 'B' for scores between 83 and 87
  - should return 'C' for scores between 73 and 77
  - should return 'D' for scores between 63 and 67
  - should return 'F' for scores between 0 and 59

I am really stuck with this and I am wondering what am I missing to get this straight.

Please help!

Comment: But your code is working. Returning 'A-'

Comment: should return 'A' for scores between 93 and 97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing second part of `else if`. Now if you do not add `-`, you will always append `+`.

```js
function convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(score) {
  var fscore;

  switch(true) {
    case (score <= 100 && score >= 90):
       fscore = 'A';
        break;
    case (score <= 89 && score >= 80):
        fscore = 'B';
         break;
    case (score <= 79 && score >= 70):
        fscore = 'C';
         break;
       case (score <= 69 && score >= 60):
        fscore = 'D';
         break;
    case (score <= 59 && score >= 0):
        fscore = 'F';
        break;

    case (score > 100 && score < 0):
        fscore = 'INVALID SCORE';
        break; 

    default:
      return 'INVALID SCORE';
  }

  if (score <= 100 && score >= 60) {
    var last_digit = score%10;
    
    if (last_digit <= 2 && score != 100) {
      fscore += '-';
    } else if (last_digit >= 8 || score == 100) {
      fscore += '+';
    }
  }

  return fscore;
}

console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(91), 'A-');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(94), 'A');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(100), 'A+');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(81), 'B-');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(84), 'B');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(88), 'B+');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(71), 'C-');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(74), 'C');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(78), 'C+');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(61), 'D-');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(64), 'D');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(68), 'D+');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(31), 'F');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(50), 'F');
console.log(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(59), 'F');
```

Comment: should return A with a plus for scores between 98 and 100

Comment: @JamesHedegon Check now